# How to fix error: angular/common@8.2.13 - dependency could not be resolved

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm, compiler-errors

I have the following compiler error - and I am trying to work out how to fix it. I have tried install different version of different libraries, but nothing seems to work.

From what I can tell, the firebaseui-angular package requires a different version of angular/fire?

```
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/service-worker@8.2.14
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@8.2.13
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   @angular/common@"8.2.13" from the root project
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=6.0.0 <9 || ^9.0.0-0" from @angular/fire@5.4.2
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/fire
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!     @angular/fire@"^5.2.3" from the root project
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!     peer @angular/fire@"^5.0.0" from firebaseui-angular@4.1.0
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!     node_modules/firebaseui-angular
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!       firebaseui-angular@"^4.0.1" from the root project
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"8.2.14" from @angular/service-worker@8.2.14
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/service-worker
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   @angular/service-worker@"~8.2.13" from the root project
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"8.2.14" from @angular/service-worker@8.2.14
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/service-worker
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!     @angular/service-worker@"~8.2.13" from the root project
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR!
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[05:14:00]: ▸ npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is the state of the my current environment.
ionic info

```
[WARN] Error loading @ionic/angular package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular/package'

       Require stack:
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic
[WARN] Error loading @ionic/angular-toolkit package.json: Error: Cannot find module
       '@ionic/angular-toolkit/package'

       Require stack:
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic
[WARN] Error loading @angular/cli package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/package'

       Require stack:
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic
[WARN] Error loading @angular-devkit/build-angular package.json: Error: Cannot find module
       '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package'

       Require stack:
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic
[WARN] Error loading @angular-devkit/schematics package.json: Error: Cannot find module
       '@angular-devkit/schematics/package'

       Require stack:
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\index.js
       - C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\bin\ionic

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.4 (C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : not installed
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : not installed
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : not installed
   @angular/cli                  : not installed
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android broken
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, cordova-plugin-ionic 5.5.3, (and 24 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   NodeJS : v16.13.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 8.1.2
   OS     : Windows 10
```

and my config.json is

```
{
  "name": "diocese-giving-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Diocese Giving App",
  "author": "Ionic Team <hi@ionicframework.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "copy.google.ios": "cp GoogleService-Info.plist ios/App/App/GoogleService-Info.plist",
    "copy.google.android": "cp google-services.json android/app/google-services.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app.git"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/pwa": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.13",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/dialogs": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-config": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-messaging": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/pin-dialog": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.2",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-calendar": "^5.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.4.7",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.4.1",
    "firebase": "^7.6.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "firebaseui": "^4.3.0",
    "firebaseui-angular": "^4.0.1",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.5.0",
    "linqts": "^1.12.6",
    "luxon": "^1.22.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-local-notification": "^1.0.1",
    "rrule": "^2.6.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.4",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.20",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.20",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.13",
    "@angular/fire": "github:angular/fire",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.2.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.17",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^10.1.2",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-non-exempt-encryption": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "^0.0.2",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.9.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-calendar": {
        "CALENDAR_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-support-google-services": {},
      "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": {},
      "cordova-plugin-browsertab": {},
      "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "com.dcms.d2u",
        "ANDROID_SCHEME": " ",
        "ANDROID_HOST": " ",
        "ANDROID_PATHPREFIX": "/"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "510f1e55",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Production",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
        "MAX_STORE": "2",
        "MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION": "30"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": XXXXXXXXX,
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.0"
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "call-number": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "4.0.0",
      "cordova-plugin-ios-non-exempt-encryption": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't have angular/cli installed? and have you tried --legacy-peer-deps?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command.

```
npm i package_name -f
```